# Keep Cookie Consent Banner hidden once Users Accepted Cookies

Tags: javascript, html

I've managed to get the cookie consent banner to work, where the cookies aren't set when the page loads. Only once the user clicks on the "Accept" button, the cookies will set and show up within the dev tool Application. Once the "Accept" button has been clicked, the banner is hidden, but only temporarily. Because when I refresh the page, or click on a different page, the cookie consent banner shows up again, even though User has already accepted cookies.

I've tried out a bunch of stuff, and am stuck on how I can keep the banner hidden, after user has accepted the cookies.

*Note*: I have a custom cookie made and use the Google Tag Manager/Google Analytics cookies.

I would appreciate any help on this! Thank you!

**HEAD SCRIPTS**

```
<head>

<!-- Cookie Consent Banner -->
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; 
  function gtag() {dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('consent', 'default', { 'ad_storage': 'denied', 'analytics_storage': 'denied' });
</script>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TAG_ID"></script> 

<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; 
  function gtag() {dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'TAG_ID');
</script>

<script>
  function consentGranted() { 
      gtag('consent', 'update', { 'ad_storage': 'granted', 'analytics_storage': 'granted' });};
</script>
<script>
  function dismissCookieBanner() { 
      gtag('consent', 'update', { 'ad_storage': 'denied', 'analytics_storage': 'denied' });};
</script>
<!-- Cookie Consent Banner -->

</head>
```

**HTML**

```
<div role="region" aria-label="cookie-consent-banner" id="cookie-banner">
<div class="cookie-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
<div class="cookie-buttons">
     <button type="button" class="accept-cookies" onclick="consentGranted()">Accept</button>
     <button type="button" class="dismiss-cookies" onclick="dismissCookieBanner()">Dismiss</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function consentGranted() {
    var cookieConsentBanner = $('#cookie-banner');
    if ( cookieConsentBanner.length ) {
        if ( Cookies.get('CUSTOM_COOKIE') != 'true' ) {
            var acceptCookieButton= cookieConsentBanner.find('.cookie-buttons .accept-cookies');    
            acceptCookieButton.on('click', function() {
                Cookies.set( 'CUSTOM_COOKIE', 'true', { expires: 365 } );
                cookieConsentBanner.remove();
            });
          };
        };
};

function dismissCookieBanner() {
    var cookieConsentBanner = $('#cookie-banner');
    var dismissCookieBanner= cookieConsentBanner.find('.cookie-buttons .dismiss-cookies');
        dismissCookieBanner.on('click', function() {
            cookieConsentBanner.remove();
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `localStorage` to store the cookie consent data, and then once the page loads, put the banner onscreen if no answer was given, else, not place it.  Example:

```js
function consentGranted() {
localStorage.setItem('consent', true)
    var cookieConsentBanner = $('#cookie-banner');
    if ( cookieConsentBanner.length ) {
        if ( Cookies.get('CUSTOM_COOKIE') != 'true' ) {
            var acceptCookieButton= cookieConsentBanner.find('.cookie-buttons .accept-cookies');    
            acceptCookieButton.on('click', function() {
                Cookies.set( 'CUSTOM_COOKIE', 'true', { expires: 365 } );
                cookieConsentBanner.remove();
            });
          };
        };
};

function dismissCookieBanner() {
localStorage.setItem('consent', false)
    var cookieConsentBanner = $('#cookie-banner');
    var dismissCookieBanner= cookieConsentBanner.find('.cookie-buttons .dismiss-cookies');
        dismissCookieBanner.on('click', function() {
            cookieConsentBanner.remove();
        });
};

document.getElementById('cookie-banner').hidden = localStorage.getItem('consent') != null
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

<!-- Cookie Consent Banner -->
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; 
  function gtag() {dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('consent', 'default', { 'ad_storage': 'denied', 'analytics_storage': 'denied' });
</script>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TAG_ID"></script> 

<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; 
  function gtag() {dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'TAG_ID');
</script>

<script>
  function consentGranted() { 
      gtag('consent', 'update', { 'ad_storage': 'granted', 'analytics_storage': 'granted' });};
</script>
<script>
  function dismissCookieBanner() { 
      gtag('consent', 'update', { 'ad_storage': 'denied', 'analytics_storage': 'denied' });};
</script>
<!-- Cookie Consent Banner -->

</head>

<h1>My site</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. Sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa. Maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque. Vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna.
</p>

<div role="region" aria-label="cookie-consent-banner" id="cookie-banner">
<div class="cookie-text">Do you accept the cookie policy?</div>
<div class="cookie-buttons">
     <button type="button" class="accept-cookies" onclick="consentGranted()">Accept</button>
     <button type="button" class="dismiss-cookies" onclick="dismissCookieBanner()">Dismiss</button>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paxkym/50aw1yec/2/)